# Schema.org markup for an Article with additionalType?

Tags: microdata, schema.org, productontology.org

I have a site that has many articles on a specific dog breed. I want to help Google and other search engines to understand this article is specifcally on this breed or a topic realted to this breed. I thought about using productontology.org to define an additional type.

For example I have the following Schema.org markup:

```html
<article itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
   <link itemprop="additionalType" href="http://www.productontology.org/id/dog_breed" />

   <!-- Additional Code + Schema.org markup -->

</article>
```

Is this the correct way to indicate with Schema.org markup that this article is on (or related to) this specific breed? If not, what is the proper way using Schema.org?

Note: I understand fully that the best way is with great content that uses keywords. However, I am looking to know how to do this from a schema.org perspective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, your example would mean that it’s an `schema:Article` *and* a `pto:Dog_breed`.

To state what the `schema:Article` is *about*, you could use its [`about` property](http://schema.org/about).

The elaborate version would be:

```html
<article itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">

  <div itemprop="about" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Intangible">
    <link itemprop="additionalType" href="http://www.productontology.org/id/Dog_breed" />
    <!-- properties about dog breed(s) -->
  </div>

  <!-- properties about the article -->

</article>
```

Notes:

- Schema.org has no class for dog breeds, so you’d have to choose the closest broader class. I think it would be [`schema:Intangible`](http://schema.org/Intangible); otherwise the top class [`schema:Thing`](http://schema.org/Thing).
- Using `pto:Dog_breed` means that the article is about the concept of dog breeds, or dog breeds in general, *but not* about a specific dog breed.
- It should be `…/id/Dog_breed`, not `…/id/dog_breed` (URIs are case-sensitive).